# Knot-less adjustment system for thin UHMWPE string

Tags: ropes, rope-management

I successfully built for myself a set of gymnastics rings using a 40 mm high tenacity nylon strap and a niteize "dual camjam" which is simply a cam buckle that does away with the need to sew one end of the strap to the buckle.

Since I'm a long time traveler, I came across a UHMWPE string used for kite-surf which is rated way above the nylon strap I'm currently using while being perhaps 1/5 the volume of the nylon strap. I successfully used the UHMWPE for my gymnastic rings in an experimental setup, so this is a very promising material for an ultra-compact portable workout system. Alas! It has been impossible to find a method to find a device to adjust the string loop length the way a ratched or the niteize "dual camjam" does, which renders my wonderfully thin and strong UHMWPE strings useless for the purpose I bought them.

Is there any device that does work as a ratchet/dual-camjam for thin strings? if so, what's the name of such a device?

Just as a note, there is a string tightener from niteize "camjam XT", but judging from most of reviews it seems to be close to useless.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Outdoors Stack. This is a good question, but you could improve it by adding a picture of your current set-up and specs/link for the UHMWPE - I suspect diameter will be the key here.

Comment: Look into "tent guyline knotless hardware". Or "Hammock setup knotless hardware". There's lots of options out there. Also, don't be afraid of some basic knot-work. A prussic with a carabiner and a single fixed loop may be all you need.

Comment: Would a "whoopie sling" work for you?    They use just the UHMWPE rope, feeding it into it's own center to make a minimal weight, easily adjustable loop.   They are almost magical.  See https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14183/which-kind-of-rope-should-i-buy-to-make-an-ultralight-hammock-suspension-system/14188#14188

Comment: what's the diameter of the string?